# How do I expand a sum?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, expression-manipulation, operators

I have a problem with *Mathematica*'s symbolic manipulations. As an example, consider the following expression:

$$\sum _{i=1}^n -2 x_i \left(-a x_i-b+y_i\right)=0$$

How do I get *Mathematica* to expand it into this form:

$$-\sum _{i=1}^n x_i y_i +a \sum _{i=1}^n x_i^2+b \sum _{i=1}^n x_i=0$$

What I mean is: what functions do I apply to get the product to expand and the summation operator to distribute?

Comment: You are requesting two changes: first to `Expand` the products in the summation and second to `Distribute` the action of `Sum` over the addition. Consulting the help pages for `Expand` and `Distribute` will answer your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Distribute @ Sum[-2 Subscript[x, i] (-a Subscript[x, i] - b + Subscript[y, i]) // Expand,
                 {i, n}] == 0
```

[image]

Comment: How can one make the 2a and 2b factors come out in front of the sums? (and in general any variables that do not depend on the summation index)?

Comment: One can play with pattern matching, e.g. let the resulting expression be `expr`, then `expr /. {Sum[Times[c_, d__], List[i_, n_]] :> c Sum[Times[d], List[i, n]]}` does what you want. In more general cases one can work with `ReplaceRepeated (//.)` and (or) restrict pattern like e.g. `c_?NumericQ`.

Answer (score 4):

I had this question also a few times, but I never bothered to solve it properly. Here is my solution, which also moves constant factors out of the sums:

```
SumExpand[exp_] := exp /. Sum[c_, {i_, a_, b_}] :> Distribute[Sum[ExpandAll[c], {i, a, b}]]
SumSimplify[exp_] := SumExpand[exp] /. Sum[c_, {i_, a_, b_}] :> Apply[Times, Extract[c, Position[D[c /. Times -> List, i], 0]]] Sum[c/Apply[Times, Extract[c, Position[D[c /. Times -> List, i], 0]]], {i, a, b}]
```

Here is an example (linear regression):

```
err = Sum[(c0 + c1 x[i] - y[i])^2, {i, 1, n}]
gl1 = D[err, c0] // SumSimplify
gl2 = D[err, c1] // SumSimplify
```

The results are:
$$err = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (c_0 + c_1 x[i] - y[i])^2$$
$$gl1 = 2 c_0 n + 2 c_1 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x[i] - 2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n y[i]$$
$$gl2 = 2 c_0 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x[i] + 2 c_1 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x[i]^2 - 2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x[i] y[i]$$

The code

```
Solve[{gl1 == 0, gl2 == 0}, {c0, c1}]
```

gives the parameters $c_0$ and $c_1$.