# Factor independent term from a summation?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

Can I factor $t^2$ from $\frac{1}{t}\sum_{n=1}^{n1}t^2Exp[-a n^2+bn]$ to get

$t\sum_{n=1}^{n1}Exp[-a n^2+bn]$ using some command?

```
1/t Sum[t^2 Exp[-a n^2 + b n], {n, 1, n1}]
```

Comment: `sum /. Sum[const_?(FreeQ[#, n] &)*expr_, iter_List] :> const*Sum[expr, iter]`

Comment: Closely related : [How do I expand a sum?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/how-do-i-expand-a-sum)