# How to make calculations involving symbolic summation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics, symbolic, summation

I want to minimize a function involving the sum of $n$ fixed (but indetermined) $x$ values, for example:

```
Minimize[Sum[(x[i] - a)^2, {i, 1, n}], a]
```

Expected answer: `Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]/n`

Is there a way to represent this sum and solve the problem symbolically?

Comment: By "known but undetermined", do you mean that they do not actually have explicit values, but are merely formal signifiers?

Comment: @thorimus Exactly!

Comment: Works fine if you set $n$ to a specific value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a solution without specifying `n`. Following the approach here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16972 to distributes the terms in the sum you could compute the extremum explicitly

```
Sum[(x[i]-a)^2,{i,1,n}]
Distribute@D[%,a]
Solve[%==0,a]
```

which gets you a candidate for an extremum at

> `a -> -Sum[-2*x[i], {i, 1, n}]/(2*n)`

which is in fact a minimum since the second derivative

```
Sum[(x[i] - a)^2, {i, 1, n}]
Distribute@D[%, a, a]
```

is positive (`2n`) for all `a`. I do not know how one could get `Minimize` to work without specifying `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
n = 4;
Minimize[Sum[(x[i] - a)^2, {i, 1, n}], a]

(*    {1/4 (3 x[1]^2 - 2 x[1] x[2] + 3 x[2]^2 - 2 x[1] x[3] - 2 x[2] x[3] + 3 x[3]^2 - 2 x[1] x[4] - 2 x[2] x[4] - 2 x[3] x[4] + 3 x[4]^2),
      {a -> 1/4 (x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4])}}    *)
```

and

```
D[Sum[(x[i] - a)^2, {i, 1, n}], a] /. a -> Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}]/n // Expand

(*    0    *)
```

Comment: Oh, that's great! I didn't think of trying to set a specific value for n. Thanks!